# Choice between two XSD groups with same name

Tags: .net, xml, xsd, xsd-1.0

I have a schema that needs to allow one of two groups of elements one or more times:

```
<xs:element name="Parent" maxOccurs="99">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="City" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Zip" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Zip" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

But validation always seems to happen at the first of the choices (it'll say Missing Element City). How can I make this work? I'm using .NET XSD 1.0 and I can't change the XML.

Answer (score 2):

This worked. I'll leave this post unanswered for a while in case anyone wants to provide a better solution or elaborate further.

```
<xs:group name="SharedElements">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="Address" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
<xs:group name="NationalElements">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="Zip" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
<xs:group name="InternationalElements">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="Zip" type="xs:string" />
    <xs:element name="Country" type="xs:string" />
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:element name="Parent" maxOccurs="99">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:group ref="SharedElements" />
      <xs:choice>
        <xs:group ref="NationalElements" />
        <xs:group ref="InternationalElements" />
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your InternationalElements include Country?